# Styling h:selectOneListbox

Tags: css, jsf

I have an issue with styling `h:selectOneListbox` and would most appreciate some advice.

In a bean I have a loop where values and labels are read in from a file and are displayed using `h:selectOneListbox`.  Most of the entries are displayed normally and can be selected, but several are displayed but are disabled.  Here is a fragment of code in a bean where the entries are initialized and where a flag is set to specify whether a given entry will be disabled.

```
// private method for initialization

// Initialization code

SelectItem item = new SelectItem();
for (i=0; i<numEls[set]; i++) {
    item = null;
    if (itemLabels[set][i].contains(disabledLabel))
        item = new SelectItem(itemValues[set][i], itemLabels[set][i], "", true); // Disabled
    else
        item = new SelectItem(itemValues[set][i], itemLabels[set][i]);           // Enabled
    if (set == 0)
        items0[i] = item;
    else
        items1[i] = item;

    // Rest of the initialization code

}

public String getElement0() {
    return element[0];
}

public void setElement0(String element) {
    this.element[0] = element;
}

// Other getters and setters, including for element[1] etc.
```

This works correctly and part of the corresponding xhtml code is:

```
<h:selectOneListbox id="abundances0" size="10" style="width:15em" value="#{abundance.element0}"
                    enabledClass="itemEnabled" disabledClass="itemDisabled">
    <f:selectItems value="#{abundance.items0}"/>
</h:selectOneListbox>
```

and in a CSS file are the following two lines:

```
.itemEnabled {font-family:monospace;}
.itemDisabled {font-family:monospace;}
```

Using Firefox the items are formatted correctly, with the disabled items also being formatted, but grayed out. For some reason, even though the style itemDisabled is exactly the same as itemEnabled, it is still grayed out. If itemDisabled is omitted, it is still grayed out, but not monospaced, which is to be expected.

However, using Internet Explorer or Chrome the text is not monospaced, neither the enabled or disabled text. How do I fix that? Also, I notice that the attributes for `h:selectOneListbox` also include styleClass, but how does that fit in with enabledClass and disabledClass?

Can somebody kindly help me on this so that the output is correctly styled using all major browsers?

---

OK, many thanks for that, and I have just started using PrimeFaces.

However, I do have another question related to this.  I tried to use f:validateDoubleRange with a range of valid input values, and produce an error message using h:message if the input is outside a specified range.  The problem is that when I do this, an action is not fired when I click a button to update the contents in the menu, which otherwise works.

Here is a more complete listing of my xhtml code:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="abundanceSet0" value="#{abundance.abunSet0}" style="height:25px; width:180px;">
  <f:selectItems value="#{abundance.abunSetMap}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
<p:spacer width="37" height="0"/>
<p:commandButton value="Select Set" actionListener="#{abundance.selectSet0}" update="abundances0"/>
<br/><br/>
<h:outputText value="Specify the abundances of individual elements:"/>
<h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="2">
  <h:selectOneListbox id="abundances0" size="10" style="width:15em" value="#{abundance.element0}"
                          enabledClass="itemEnabled" disabledClass="itemDisabled">
    <f:selectItems value="#{abundance.items0}"/>
  </h:selectOneListbox>
  <h:panelGrid style="text-align:center;">
  <p:commandButton type="button" value="Readme" onclick="openPopup(600,500,'htmlPopup/expAbundances')" styleClass="longButton"/>
    <h:inputText id="update0" size="4" value="#{abundance.updateAbun0}"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Update Abundance" actionListener="#{abundance.update0}"
                     styleClass="longButton" update="abundances0">
      <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="-9.99" maximum="12.00"/>
  </h:panelGrid>

  <ui:include src="abunExplain.xhtml"/>

</h:panelGrid>
```

The actions abundance.selectSet0 and abundance.update0, as well as others, are not fired.  The file here is included in a main file which displays the whole page, and even validating entries in that file prevents actions to work.  Incidentally, you can ignore "abunExplain.xhtml" which just adds some static text to the view.

For the time being I am using some methods in my bean to intercept input values and make sure they are valid numbers in range.

If you or somebody has some ideas about this, I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 1):

This is a HTML specific problem, not a JSF specific problem. The HTML `<option>` element which is generated by `<f:selectItem(s)>` in a `<h:selectOneListbox>` has by itself already very limited CSS styling options. Only the font color can be changed across browsers and anything else is browser dependent.

Your best bet is to use JavaScript to turn the `<select><option>` into an `<ul><li>`, which is exactly what the most JSF component libraries are doing like PrimeFaces with [`<p:selectOneListbox>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectOneListbox.jsf). The `<ul><li>` allows full CSS styling freedom. You could even use some standalone jQuery (UI) plugin for this — but why reinventing the wheel if for example PrimeFaces is already doing exactly that.

Comment: Many thanks, I have in fact just started using Primefaces and am in the process of changing some of my tags to PrimeFaces.